# Open activity after intent 'click on phone number'

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I found several answers on this issue, but it's not working for me. If you click a phone number in an email or on a website, a default dialer popup comes up to select the dialer/skype etc.

I'm trying to get my app in that list - so I don't want to handle the actual call, but open the activity and show the number the user clicked on.

I've tried this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyOutgoingCallHandler">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DIAL" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But it's not showing in the list. What intent should I filter for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an `Activity` to the list of `Activity`s that will be shown to the user as possible phone dialers, you need to have an `Activity` and the `<activity>` definition must contain this `intent-filter>` in the manifest:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What you've got is a `BroadcastReceiver` that will receive the outgoing call `Intent`. That's something different.

Answer (score 0):

The official [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html) has covered this process.  You can read all about it there.

Your intent filter looks like it has the correct action, so it may be that you have not requested the correct Android permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Here is how the Android Developers blog suggest you declare the broadcast receiver.

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />  
    <application>
        ...
        <receiver android:name=MyOutgoingCallHandler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```